# Bitnami Apache Server not starting

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, bitnami

I was editing my site today with beaver builder when suddenly my site crashed and when I refreshed I got

```
This site can’t be reached. 
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

I went onto my bitnami control panel and tried to restart the server multiple times, but it wouldn't start.  In the error logs I got:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 1
Stdout:

Stderr:
Unknown error starting apache
```

I then went onto the apache error log and found:

```html
[Wed Jul 04 10:31:37.109219 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3704:tid 768] AH00428: Parent: child process 5756 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Wed Jul 04 10:31:37.752200 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3704:tid 768] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:37:14.954957 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8144:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:37:15.001831 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8144:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 10:37:15.079952 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8144:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:49.750389 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11120:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:49.797262 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11120:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:49.891009 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11120:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:53.860011 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9936:tid 552] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:53.906885 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9936:tid 552] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:53.985007 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9936:tid 552] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:57.656824 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4048:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:57.719322 2018] [core:warn] [pid 4048:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 10:43:57.813067 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4048:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:49:59.141463 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11876:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 10:49:59.219595 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11876:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 10:49:59.303602 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11876:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:03:33.808215 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2500:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:03:33.855087 2018] [core:warn] [pid 2500:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:03:33.933211 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2500:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:12:49.220147 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11312:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:12:49.271789 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11312:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:12:49.349912 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11312:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:13:02.303385 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9232:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:13:02.334634 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9232:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:13:02.412756 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9232:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:00.757696 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5084:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:00.817871 2018] [core:warn] [pid 5084:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:00.895825 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5084:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:04.061023 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10132:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:04.123523 2018] [core:warn] [pid 10132:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:04.201643 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10132:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:06.828389 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11468:tid 652] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:06.875263 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11468:tid 652] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:06.953385 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11468:tid 652] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:09.599994 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9660:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:09.662497 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9660:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:09.740616 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9660:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:12.375429 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8288:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:12.422307 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8288:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:12.500426 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8288:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:15.125950 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9092:tid 656] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:15.172824 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9092:tid 656] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:15.250946 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9092:tid 656] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:17.896768 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3224:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:17.928018 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3224:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:18.006140 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3224:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:20.688481 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 856:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:20.750982 2018] [core:warn] [pid 856:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:20.829099 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 856:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:23.444364 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13872:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:23.491238 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13872:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:15:23.569362 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13872:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:39.966853 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9348:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:40.029369 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9348:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:40.123097 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9348:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:52.949312 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8544:tid 636] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:53.011828 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8544:tid 636] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:23:53.089932 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8544:tid 636] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:01.888380 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7788:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:01.935256 2018] [core:warn] [pid 7788:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:02.013377 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7788:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:19.034885 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2504:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:19.081759 2018] [core:warn] [pid 2504:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:24:19.159881 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2504:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:27:44.485422 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13956:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:27:44.516671 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13956:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:27:44.610419 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13956:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:30:26.071320 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8432:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:30:26.133822 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8432:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:30:26.211942 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8432:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:33:09.312825 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13932:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:33:09.375326 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13932:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:33:09.469070 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13932:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:35:56.672924 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4588:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:35:56.735428 2018] [core:warn] [pid 4588:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:35:56.829171 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4588:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:36:01.704159 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11436:tid 504] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:36:01.751037 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11436:tid 504] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:36:01.829154 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 11436:tid 504] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:37:58.576022 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7832:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:37:58.638520 2018] [core:warn] [pid 7832:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:37:58.716640 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7832:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:42:27.467377 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 12180:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:42:27.608001 2018] [core:warn] [pid 12180:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:42:27.701744 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 12180:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:45:06.946836 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13248:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:45:06.993711 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13248:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:45:07.071833 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13248:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:54:18.906039 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8252:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 04 11:54:18.968539 2018] [core:warn] [pid 8252:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/Made In Your Design/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jul 04 11:54:19.046659 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8252:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I've found a few similar posts but none of them have the exact error, and I've wasted a lot of time already trying to find the solution that I actually need.

I'm also not familiar with the set up of .conf files etc so I may have found the answer already and just not understood it.

For reference I'm using Port 83 and SSL Port 447.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I really don't want to lose the work I've done over the last few days setting this site up.

Update: I've tried changing the .conf file to "Listen 84" etc and it still isn't working.

Update 2: I tried to do a completely fresh install of bitnami and the apache wouldn't start on that either i got this error:

> [Wed Jul 04 17:07:05.398009 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10164:tid 500] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:07:05.523004 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10164:tid 500] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:07:27.238300 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10576:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:07:27.310879 2018] [core:warn] [pid 10576:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/bitnami test 1/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:07:27.404621 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10576:tid 644] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:08:18.527849 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10900:tid 504] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:08:18.575236 2018] [core:warn] [pid 10900:tid 504] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/bitnami test 1/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:08:18.653354 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10900:tid 504] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:09:27.676546 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13016:tid 664] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:09:27.732512 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13016:tid 664] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/bitnami test 1/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>   [Wed Jul 04 17:09:27.824454 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13016:tid 664] AH01909: localhost:447:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

I have tried new installs on different ports, and the same ports with no luck.

Comment: Your SSL certificate...  have you generated it yourself? if so is it for localhost?

Comment: As far as I know, I didn't set up an SSL certificate - I'm not sure why bitnami has an SSL port set up.  I think it assigns that port automatically on set up.

Comment: It is hard to just guess what is actually causing this error, may be its the .conf file or some thing else, the warning suggest SSL issue try turning that port of, or you can try solution mentioned in this link: https://community.bitnami.com/t/apache-does-not-work-after-windows-10-upgrade/36035/40

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.  The most annoying thing about it is that it was working this morning without issue.  I didn't install anything and all I was doing was editing pages.  Very confused as to what's causing the issue.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. As I mentioned in our [community forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/unknown-error-starting-apache-starting-apache-web-server-exit-code-1/58803), in case you find this problem in the future, please try to start Apache manually and share the output of this command `C:/Bitnami/site name/apache2/bin/apache.exe -f "C:/Bitnami/site name/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"`

Answer (score 0):

My problem with this error was that I had another program running on same port that I treid to start Bitnami. I just terminated the task and started the Bitnami servers.

I terminated the task in command line using administrator with command

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

I found port 80 PID with command

```
netstat -ano | findstr :80
```